# If statements clearing controls from panels by themsemselves

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

I’m having an issue with the methods clearing my panels and I can’t see why. I have checked all over my code and can’t see why it would clear my `PlayerPanel`.

From what I can tell I haven't called `PlayerPanel.Controls.Clear()` or `PlayerPanel.Controls.Refresh();` anywhere except for one button that has it as a click event.

From my testing I’ve found that if a comment out the `if then else` in `GameDecider()` the program doesn’t clear the panel but I cant tell why.

```
private void ConfirmButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (currentPlayerDog == null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
       if(currentPlayerDog.GetChosenValue()!= "")
       {
          DrawCardButton.Visible = false;SelectedChoiceLabel.Visible = true;ConfirmButton.Visible = false; NextRoundButton.Visible = true;

          string pl1attk = currentPlayerDog.GetChosenValue();
          string pl2attk = currentComputerDog.GetComputerAttkValue(currentPlayerDog.GetChosenAttk());
                    SelectedChoiceLabel.Text = "you attack with " + currentPlayerDog.GetChosenAttk() + " " + pl1attk + " | " + "Computer attacks with " + currentPlayerDog.GetChosenAttk() + " " + pl2attk;
          currentComputerDog.SetTextVisible();                   
          GameDecider();
          RanOutOfCards();
          currentPlayerDog.SetSelection = "";
       }
       else
       {
          //RanOutOfCards();
       }                  
   }            
}

private void PlayerWon()
{   
   round = 0;
   currentPlayerDog.SetTextVisible();
   currentComputerDog.SetTextVisible();
   playerCards.Add(currentComputerDog);
   playerCards.Add(currentPlayerDog);
   currentComputerDog.Left = 0;
   currentComputerDog.Top = 0;
   currentPlayerDog.Left = 0;
   currentPlayerDog.Top = 0;

   try
   {
       for (int count = 0; count < playerCards.Count; count++)
       {
           PlayerDeckPanel.Controls.Add(playerCards[count]);
       }         
    }
    catch
    {
    }            
}

private void ComputerWon()
{
   round = 1;
   currentPlayerDog.SetTextHidden();
   currentComputerDog.SetTextHidden();
   computerCards.Add(currentComputerDog);
   computerCards.Add(currentPlayerDog);
   currentComputerDog.Left = 0;
   currentComputerDog.Top = 0;
   currentPlayerDog.Left = 0;
   currentPlayerDog.Top = 0;

   try
   {   
      for (int count = 0; count < computerCards.Count; count++)
      {
         ComputerDeckPanel.Controls.Add(computerCards[count]);
      }
   }
   catch
   {
   }    
}

private void IsDrool(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
    {
       PlayerWon();
    }
    else
    {
       ComputerWon();
    }
}

private void NotDrool(int a ,int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
       PlayerWon();
    }
    else
    {
       ComputerWon();
    }
}

private void GameDecider()
{
   string pl1attk = currentPlayerDog.GetChosenValue();
   string pl2attk = currentComputerDog.GetComputerAttkValue(currentPlayerDog.GetChosenAttk());
   int pl1 = Convert.ToInt32(pl1attk);
   int pl2 = Convert.ToInt32(pl2attk);

   if (pl1 == pl2)
   {
      PlayerWon();
   }

   if (currentPlayerDog.GetChosenAttk() != "Drool")
   {
      NotDrool(pl1, pl2);         
   }
   else
   {
      IsDrool(pl1, pl2);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. There is just too much irrelevant code here that prevents you from seeing the answer

Comment: Comment out each line in the PlayerWon() and ComputerWon() methods and gradually reintroduce them to find which line is causing the issue.

Comment: Use the debugger to make sure the panels are indeed cleared and not just the children invisible or moved out of sight etc..